# Adjust the value of a reccuring numeric property in CSS instead of overriding it

Tags: css

Consider the following code:

```
[example.htm]
<link rel="stylesheet" src="myStyle.css" />
<style>
    div {margin-left: 100px} /* let's assume this margin value is dynamically generated in PHP/ASP/JSP and we dont't have control over it */
</style>
<body>
    <div>foo</div>
    <div class="indent-me-more-please">bar</div> <!-- let's assume we don't have control over this part, either -->
</body>
```

and

```
[myStyle.css]
.indent-me-more-please {margin-left: * !important}
```

Is it possible to set the margin value (marked as `*`) to be always 50px greater than the value would have when it would only be set in the `<style>` tag or e.g. in the element attribute? In this case: 100px+50px = 150px. Something like "`margin-left += 50px;`" Something to call, I don't know, relative value incrementing?

Is it possible to do this in pure CSS?

Comment: You mention `margin-left += 50px;`, this would work with jQuery and would be considered the correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

CSS does not support that.

In your particular example, you could use `padding-left` to add additional space.

Answer (score 0):

this need a different type of language like **SASS** http://sass-lang.com/ in sass you can add variables e.g

```
$margin-left: 50px;
#container{
 margin = $margin-left + 10px;
}
```

but to use sass you need to prepare your server for it ...

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with jQuery

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/kevinPHPkevin/EJzue/

```
$('div').css('margin-left', function (index, curValue) {
    return parseInt(curValue, 10) + 100 + 'px';
});
```